# AngularJS - change href Attribute based on current path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-href

How can I change the value of the href-Attribute based on the current path?

My if clause in AngularJS looks like this:

```
    if (newPath.indexOf('test') > -1) {
      // change the value of the href-Attribute
    } else {
      // don't change the value of the href-Attribute
    }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <li>
      <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="/path1/path2/path4">Downloads</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `ng-href` to dynamically assign value to href

```
<li>
  <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" ng-href="{{myVar}}">Downloads</a>
</li>

$scope.myVar ="/path1/path2/path4";

if (newPath.indexOf('test') > -1) {
      $scope.myVar = "/path1/path2/path4" // you can assign whatever path to this variable 
} else {
      $scope.myVar = "/path1/path2/path3" // you can assign whatever path to this variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current path with

```
var url = $location.absUrl().split('?')[0];
```

Replace href attribute

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#selector' ) );
myEl.attr('href',url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (newPath.indexOf('test') > -1) {
      $scope.newPath = newPath.test;
    } else {
      // don't change the value of the href-Attribute
    }

<li>
      <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" ng-href="{{newPath}}">Downloads</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!